# Negative lookahead regex not working in Java

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, regex-lookarounds

The following regex successfully works when testing [here](https://regex101.com/r/gB6zA9/1), but when I try to implement it into my Java code, it won't return a match. It uses a negative lookahead to ensure no newlines occur between `MAIN LEVEL` and `Bedrooms`. Why won't it work in Java?

**regex**

`^\s*\bMAIN LEVEL\b\n(?:(?!\n\n)[\s\S])*\bBedrooms:\s*(.*)`

**Java**

```
pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\s*\\bMAIN LEVEL\\b\\n(?:(?!\\n\\n)[\\s\\S])*\\bBedrooms:\\s*(.*)");
    match = pattern.matcher(content);      
    if(match.find())
    {
        //Doesn't reach here
        String bed = match.group(1);
        bed = bed.trim();
    }
```

`content`  is just a string read from a text file, which contains the exact text shown in the demo linked above.

```
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\ME\\Desktop\\content.txt"); 
 content = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
```

**UPDATE:**

I changed my code to include a multiline modifier `(?m)`, but it prints out "null".

```
pattern = Pattern.compile("(?m)^\\s*\\bMAIN LEVEL\\b\\n(?:(?!\\n\\n)[\\s\\S])*\\bBedrooms:\\s*(.*)");
    match = pattern.matcher(content);
    if(match.find())
    {   // Still not reaching here
        mainBeds=match.group(1);
        mainBeds= mainBeds.trim();
    }
  System.out.println(mainBeds);     // Prints null
```

Comment: add multiline modifier `(?m)` at the start..

Comment: ie, `Pattern.compile("(?m)^\\s*\\bMAIN LEVEL\\b\\n(?:(?!\\n\\n)[\\s\\S])*\\bBedrooms:\\s*(.*)");`

Comment: Thanks @AvinashRaj but it's returning `null`. I've updated my question to reflect the changes. Any ideas??

Comment: If I simply use `pattern = Pattern.compile("Bedrooms:\\s(\\d+)");` then it properly prints`666`.

Comment: is `match` a `Matcher` obj? `Matcher match = pattern.matcher(content);`

Comment: I initialize like this:     `static  Matcher match;
    static  Matcher matcher;` This seems wrong somehow

Comment: put `System.out.println(mainBeds);` inside the if block.

Comment: Just tried and it doesn't print, since it isn't entering the `if`... meaning no matches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The problem:

As explained in [Alan Moore's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34477849/1253136), it's a mismatch between the format of the `Line-Separators` used in your file (`\r\n`), and what your pattern is specifying (`\n`):

**Original code:**
`Pattern.compile("^\\s*\\bMAIN LEVEL\\b`***`\\n`***`(?:(?!`***`\\n\\n`***`)[\\s\\S])*\\bBedrooms:\\s*(.*)");`

Note: I explain what the `\r` and `\n` represent, and the context and difference between `\r\n` and `\n`, in the second item of the *"side notes"* section.

---

### The solution(s):

1. **Most/all Java versions:**
   You can use `\r?\n` to match both formats, and this is *sufficient in most cases*.
2. **Most/all Java versions:**
   You can use `\u000D\u000A|[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029]` to match *"Any Unicode linebreak sequence"*.
3. **Java 8 and later:**
   You can use the [Linebreak Matcher (`\R`)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#lineending). It is equivalent to the second method (above), and whenever possible (Java 8 or later), ***this is the recommended method***.

**Resulting code (3rd method):**
`Pattern.compile("^\\s*\\bMAIN LEVEL\\b`***`\\R`***`(?:(?!`***`\\R\\R`***`)[\\s\\S])*\\bBedrooms:\\s*(.*)");`

---

### Side notes:

1. You can replace `\\R\\R` with `\\R{2}`, which is more readable.
2. Different formats of line-breaks exist and are used in different systems because early OSs inherited the "line-break logic" from mechanical typing machines, like typewriters.

   The `\r` in code represents a ***Carriage-Return***, aka ***`CR`***. The idea behind this is to return the typing cursor to the start of the line.

   The `\n` in code represents a ***Line-Feed***, aka ***`LF`***. The idea behind this is to move the typing cursor to the next line.

   The most common line-break formats are `CR-LF` (`\r\n`), used primarily by Windows; and `LF` (`\n`), used by most UNIX-like systems. This is the reason why *"`\r?\n` will be **sufficient** in most cases"*, and you can reliably use it for systems intended for household-grade users.

   ***However***, some (rare) OSs, usually in industrial-grade stuff such as servers, may use `CR`, `LF-CR`, or something else entirely, which is why the second method has so many characters in it, so if you *need* the code to be compatible with ***every*** system, you will *need* the second, or preferably, the third method.
3. Here is a useful method for testing where your patterns are failing:

   ```
   String content = "..."; //Replace "..." with your content.
   String patternString = "..."; //Replace "..." with your pattern.
   String lastPatternSuccess = "None. You suck at Regex!";
   for (int i = 0; i <= patternString.length(); i++) {
     try {
       String patternSubstring = patternString.substring(0, i);
       Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternSubstring);
       Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);
       if (matcher.find()) {
         lastPatternSuccess = i + " - Pattern: " + patternSubstring + " - Match: \n" + matcher.group();
       }
     } catch (Exception ex) {
       //Ignore and jump to next
     }
   }
   System.out.println(lastPatternSuccess);
   ```

Comment: Okay, this does improve on my answer, and that troubleshooting gimmick is pretty cute!

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it out when I get home and report back.

Comment: @AlanMoore Thank you! =)

Comment: @AlmightyR, I actually had been aware of this requirement for either `\r\n` or `\n` depending on the system, but this totally escaped me last night. Regardless, your answer helped me understand the reason for this difference, so thank you. I ended up using `\\R` and `\\R{2}`. Quick question: I had to remove the `^` from the beginning of the line for the regex to find a match. This is strange since I copied the demo text directly from the printed `content`. Could removal of `^` be required due to the following code using a delimiter? `content = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();` Thx

Comment: @JimJim [That might be the case](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#lt): *"By default, the regular expressions `^` and `$` ignore line terminators and only match at the beginning and the end, respectively, of the entire input sequence. If `MULTILINE` mode is activated then `^` matches at the beginning of input and after any line terminator except at the end of input. When in `MULTILINE`mode `$` matches just before a line terminator or the end of the input sequence."*

Answer (score 2):

It's the line separators.  You're looking for `\n`, but your file actually uses `\r\n`.  If you're running Java 8, you can change every `\\n` in your code to `\\R` (the universal line separator).  For Java 7 or earlier, use `\\r?\\n`.

Comment: You need to make **all** the line separators `\r\n` to see what I'm talking about.  The first `\n` in the regex fails to match the first line separator (after `MAIN LEVEL`), and if you fix that, the negative lookahead (`(?!\\n\\n)`) incorrectly matches the blank lines between sections, causing the regex to match the whole string.

Comment: Removed obsolete comments. Answer explains the issue and solution in clear, concise manner; +1. But I think I can do better, so I'm going to shamelessly copy-&-improve (with due credit).

Comment: Yes, this was the issue Alan. Thank you. However (as explained in the comment above), I had to remove the leading caret `^` from my Java code in order to function, despite the properly functioning demo text above being copied from the code's  `content` string. I'm wondering if this has to do with using a delimiter after retrieving the file as so: 
`File file = new File("C:\\Users\\ME\\Desktop\\content.txt");                        
    content = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();` Thoughts?